# Roundcube shows "www" in email address after login

Tags: postfix, dovecot, roundcube

After login to roundcube email address is like this: user@www.example.com

In postfix config file I have changed these lines to:

```
myhostname = example.com

mydomain = example.com

myorigin = $myhostname
```

In config.inc.php I changed these ones:

```
$config['default_host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$config['mail_domain'] = '%n';
```

If I remove the second line, the email address changes to **user@127.0.0.1**

And when I change it to

```
$config['mail_domain'] = '%d';
```

I get the port number at the end of the address. Since I'm serving http on port 8080 they become **user@example.com:8080**

I removed postfix dovecot and roundcube and reinstalled, but got the same results.

How can I get rid of www in the email address? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Postfix config will have no effect on the address in Roundcube. Is there anything stopping you just using `$config['mail_domain'] = 'example.com';`?

Comment: @USDMatt thanks. i didn't know i can do it !! so what is mydomain in postfix config file? problem solved. now i can send email but i can't receive . can it be related to these config files? or it's a firewall problem?

Comment: See http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydomain for details on Postfix configuration options. (That link actually goes straight to `mydomain`). The receive problem could be lots of things but I doubt it's anything to do with Roundcube config.